# Filter Sequelize with date-fns

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, date-fns

I'm trying to use `isToday` method of `date-fns` to filter records that were saved today in the database. Can I do this within the sequelize query?
Below the way I'm trying to do:

```
import { isToday } from 'date-fns';
import Buy from '../models/Buy';

class VolumeController {
  // Exibir o total de Bitcoins comprados e vendidos no dia
  async show(req, res) {
    const buys = await Buy.findAll({
      where: {
        created_at: isToday(created_at),
      },
      attributes: ['id'', 'buy_value', 'quantity', 'created_at'],
    });

    return res.json({ buys });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it as follows. I used the `startOfDay` and `endOfDay` methods of the `date-fns` library. I also need the `between` operator from the `sequelize` library.

```
import { Op } from 'sequelize';
import { startOfDay, endOfDay } from 'date-fns';
import Buy from '../models/Buy';

class VolumeController {
  // Exibir o total de Bitcoins comprados e vendidos no dia
  async show(req, res) {
    const today = new Date();

    const buys = await Buy.findAll({
      where: {
        created_at: {
          [Op.between]: [startOfDay(today), endOfDay(today)],
        },
      },
      attributes: ['id', 'account_id', 'buy_value', 'quantity', 'created_at'],
    });

    return res.json({ buys });
  }
}

export default new VolumeController();
```